# Error occurred while creating new notebook in Jupyter Notebook [Permission Denied]

Tags: python, windows, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to open new notebook in Jupyter Notebook. [But it's **denies** my permission](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2EA7Z.png).

Along this problem when I try to open one of directories it's throws an [**Server Error**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7Pm3.png) ,It's occurs in every directory

I'm using **conda version 4.4.10** , **Windows 7 Professional** (*if it helps*)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Launch anaconda as administrator .

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but this is an officer computer so I can't every time run it as administrator, couldn't we do something else?

Answer (score 4):

It is not a very good idea to run as admin because you may mess up the whole system by putting commands unless you really know what you are doing(professionally). We generally work with computers under "Admin privilege".

What you need to do is, to make sure you are at `"c:\users\your username"`. If you are not there: type `"c: cd\Users\your username"`.

You are probably at `"C:\> "` when you  try to open `"jupyter notebook"`. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

This error occurred due to window defender .
add jupyter app to allowed app in firewall & protection .
i hope the problem is solved.

Comment: Thank you for your response. But running it as an administrator helps to solve this problem, it was due to not running it as admin.

Answer (score 0):

if you are going through anaconda prompt. just click on Anaconda navigator and lanch jupyter  notebook from here, if your page opened in internet explorer just copy URL and paste in chrome and now re-try to create a new notebook. I hope it will work